# Alias to run multiple independent commands

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Is it possible to create an Oh-My-Zsh alias that will run multiple commands that each take over the terminal window? For example, I'd like to create an alias to start my Node.js app, which would include:

```
$ mongod
$ redis-server
$ cd [app_location]
$ pm2 start processes.json
```

...and a few others

I'm aware of the `mongod; redis-server; cd ...; pm2...` syntax, but this runs everything within the same window, only showing the output for the first command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using an Alfred workflow.